# How can I get the size of the keyboard on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the keyboard size *without* using `NSNotification`. When I press the plus button, it can replace the keyboard with a custom `UIView` like this:

[image: Picture1]

Then the plus button is pressed and the view loaded:

[image: Picture2]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the notification?  Seems far more efficient than guessing or having to hard code in frames and write a bunch of branches.

Comment: I agree with CodaFi, and also I think your developing on the iOS will go much better if you try to do things in the way that Apple is encouraging you to do them.

Comment: int keyboardheight;
    if (IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        keyboardheight = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        keyboardheight = 260;
    }

Comment: keyboard height is not a type of constant, height may change even after keyboard is presented. your comment is misleading

Comment: @AouiaiauoEyjaajeyio: If it is only portrait oreintation then it's height will be 260 and 100 if iphone_5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already made same rookie mistake like you want to do here. The problem is you will write a lot only to realize you do not want to avoid standard flow provided you by iOS team. For example you will definitely have a bad time dealing with issue like this one (there is additional bar which is part of standard keyboard for Chinese locale):

[image]

I solved this by using other people's work from [DAKeyboardControl project](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl). You do not need to attach observer (or if you use DAKeyboardControl - block) directly to your bar with buttons, but to your controller and check what user is trying to do and animate this bar accordingly. In the sources you can see how to get keyboard's animation duration and timing function. It may sound more complicated than it indeed is, just give it a try.

Comment: I am totally biased, but I approve =)  `DAKeyboardControl` was built for much more, but it's return block will provide you with the frame of the keyboard, and you don't need to use it's panning feature.